# Prevent MVC Web Api to load default Get

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, default

I have Products two functions setup in my ProductController

```
public IEnumerable<ProductResponse> Get()

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("search")]
public IEnumerable<ProductResponse> SearchProducts([FromUri]string keyword)
```

Calling /api/products makes Get() function to executesand I get list of all products. Calling /api/products/search/?keyword="test" makes SearchProduct() function to execute and I get list of all products filtered by keyword.

However when I call /api/products/search/ without keyword parameter specified I would like to return error, but instead Get() function executes. How can I prevent controller from defaulting to Get() function and return error if parameter is not specified.  Here is my routes.

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "products", action = "search" }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Change your `WebApiConfig` like this and also change the order

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/values/{action}", defaults: new { controller = "values" });
```

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: So I've edited second line in WebApiCOnfig to look likie this config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ProductSearch",
                routeTemplate: "api/products/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "products" }
            );

but that did not do anything. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @VladimirKuzin remember to place your route before default route as default route will capture the request before the customized one. i.e place this line first and then  put DefaultApi route